# Unable to create MySQL database even with permissions

Tags: mysql, linux, database, permissions

I'm running MySQL server Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL).
Despite the user having all required permissions, unable to create database;

```
create database meta_info;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' to database 'meta_info'
```

I fetched the permissions, and the user seems to have all the permissions, like root.

```
show grants for 'user1'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user1@localhost                |
+------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `user1`@`localhost` |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SHOW GRANTS for 'user1'@'%';
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `user1`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                                                           |
| GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `user1`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION |
```

Are there any missing permissions?

Comment: Have you tried the following : 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user1'@'localhost';`

Comment: Runnig this as 'user1' gives sames error. Anyway, based on output of ```show grants``` user1 already has *.*

Comment: it looks like it supersedes the wildcard `%` with the defined host `localhost`. Have you tried revoking the privileges for `user1`@`localhost` ?

Answer (score 0):

After you change privileges did you run "`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`" ?otherwise you changes wont affect.

Comment: This only applies if you manually changed the privileges table via INSERT, UPDATE DELETE. MySQL already knows that the privileges have been changed via the `GRANT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issues. Admin had given access to 'user1' twice, one as 'user1'@'localhost' and another as 'user1'@'%'. In first case, it did not have all the permissions, while it did have in 2nd case. So I did `DROP USER 'user1'@'localhost'` and it solved the error.

However, I'm not sure why mysql server would refer to permissions of 'localhost' entry while `show grants` reads from '%' row.